# Convert DATE format in Informix-4GL

Tags: date, informix, date-formatting

How can I convert DATE format from this (`mm/dd/yyyy`) to this format (`dd/mm/yyyy`)?
Do I need to use to_char() function? 
If I have to, how can i use it?

Answer (score 4):

Unless my memory is letting me down badly:

```
DEFINE date_val DATE
DEFINE str_date CHAR(10)

LET date_val = MDY(12, 25, 2014)
LET str_date = date_val USING "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

If you have a string in the 'mm/dd/yyyy' format and want a string in the 'dd/mm/yyyy' format, then:

```
DEFINE in_str CHAR(10)
DEFINE out_str CHAR(10)

LET in_str = "12/25/2014"
LET out_str = in_str[4,6], in_str[1,3], in_str[7,10]
```

I'm getting abominably rusty; I think those substrings are correct (using `[start,end]` rather than `[start,len]` or `[start:end]` or …), but I reserve the right to be wrong on the details of the notation — the concept is correct.